# Limit user access to user identified by IP address only 5 times a day

Tags: php

I need to limit the access to a PHP web page for a user identified by IP address only 5 times a day.

I have done this funcionality with sessions, but in the requirements I have to that with IP Adresses abd not with sessions.

Any idea on the simplest method to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may want to re-think those requirements.  An IP address does not uniquely identify a user.  One user can use many IP addresses to access your system, and many users can use one IP address.  While there is definitely a place for limiting resources by IP, don't use it so broadly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit Daily Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368419/limit-daily-access)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, create a table with columns such as:

```
|-----------------------------------|
| IP varchar(15) | Views tinyint(1) |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Then on each view either insert the IP (if its not already in the database) or increment views by 1. If views = 5 then kill the page and don't allow the user to visit.

You can then run a cron each night at 00:00 that deletes all data in the table (see: `truncate`).

Comment: keep in mind that tinyint(1) has an upper limit of 127/255 (signed/unsigned) so if your needs ever change and you need more than that you'll need to adjust your field.

Answer (score 3):

On every access, save the IP address (`UNIQUE` field) into a database together with the current date/time and a counter. Increase the counter and update the date/time every access if the IP address already exixts in the database.

Now you can just deny acces when the counter is **greater than** `5` **and** date/time is **not** one day old.

However, consider what Brad said to you. IP address is not a reliable method to identify an user.

Answer (score 2):

*Building on Prisoner's answer:*

I'd add a date field to this table and do an insert ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Bonus field: `ip_log_page` so you can use this on multiple pages.

you can also run a delete query based on the date to delete stuff from yesterday and before - either cron or just part of the script on a web page.

```
CREATE TABLE ip_log
(
    ip_log_ip VARCHAR(40),
    ip_log_date DATE,
    ip_log_visits TINYINT(1),
    ip_log_page varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ip_log_page,ip_log_ip,ip_log_date),
);
```

*keep in mind that tinyint(1) has an upper limit of 127/255 (signed/unsigned) so if your needs ever change and you need more than that you'll need to adjust your field*

Comment: by the way, varchar(40) is large enough to hold IPv6 ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [apc cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [Zend cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html) to stored the IP that you'd get from [`$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`](http://ro.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)