# Wordpress show content only once to guest visit if else something

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

How can I set in a custom page template a php condition that shows this page only once to each visit and then, in their second , third visit, automatically execute another link.

This is a one page website of those you scroll down and in the first page there is this "game - form" some sort of calculator of the day of death, I need to only show it once to guest visits... not logged.

I have tried with some php formulas I found online but not giving me results...i get error message

How can I implement this code in wordpress?? Should I place it in the header?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime']))
{
    setcookie("firsttime", "no", /* EXPIRE */);
    header('Location: first-time.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
    header('Location: site.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry, can you give me a more accurate suggestion so I can understand how it works and apply to my situation?? many thanks for the hints...

Comment: No. This question is a poor fit for S.O. as it stands because there isn't any one right answer, therefore it will lead to a ton of speculation and generalization. You'll need to investigate and implement and if your code doesn't work or you get stuck at some point with your code, then come back and we'll review the code in question. Also this question has been asked 100 times. let's take the top question from the "RELATED" sidebar. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368419/limit-daily-access?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368419/limit-daily-access?rq=1)

Comment: I added the code I'm trying to use... hope this helps to make the qustion better, the thing is how to implement such a code in wordpress. thanks...

Comment: You need to [capture a Wordpress Hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)